# Redering out a view based on dropdown value in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I would like to render a different view for 4 dropdown values in the controller. I'm new to PHP and Laravel and just starting to understand it.

**dropdown html:**

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <select name="employees" class="form-control @error('employees') is-invalid @enderror">
 <option value="">-- {{ __('choose') }} --</option>
 <option value="micro">1 - 5</option>
 <option value="small">5 - 50</option>
 <option value="medium">50 - 500</option>
 <option value="large">500 +</option>
 </select>
```

**Controller:**

```
class RegisterControllerStep2 extends Controller
{

    public function form()
    {
        return view('auth.register_step2');
    }

    public function saveData(Request $request)
    {
        auth()->user()->update($request->only(['company_name', 'website', 'employees']));

        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
}
```

I want to redirect the user to another page other than home based on their selection from the employees dropdown above.

Comment: Would you use Jquery ?, I'm asking this because with jQuery it'd be easier to do

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this

```
public function saveData(Request $request)
{
    auth()->user()->update($request->only(['company_name', 'website', 'employees']));

    if($request->employees==='micro'){
        return redirect()->route('micro');
    }

    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

Another thought I had on this is you could also do something like

```
return redirect()->route($request->employees);
```

As long as you had all your routes set up correctly with matching names to the values in your employees select

Answer (score 0):

For giving a better experience I add this jquery function to justrusty's answer.
By doing this, it is not required for the user to press submit button for changes being applied.

Add a form with an id on the select:

```
<form action="something" method="post">
@csrf

 <select id="employees" name="employees" class="form-control @error('employees') is-invalid @enderror">
 <option value="">-- {{ __('choose') }} --</option>
 <option value="micro">1 - 5</option>
 <option value="small">5 - 50</option>
 <option value="medium">50 - 500</option>
 <option value="large">500 +</option>
 </select>

</form>
```

Then add below jquery to the end of body section:

```
 $('#employees').change(function() {
    this.form.submit();
});
```

And at last, as justrusty said, redirect to the desired page in the controller:

```
if($request->employees==='micro'){
    return redirect()->route('micro');
}
```